# JOIN not retrieving rows

Tags: php, mysql

The user that is logged in has `userid`=8.  I want the query to return ALL rows in the product table but don't display the like or dislike code if `userid`=8 has voted.

With the query below no rows are being returned.  I shouldn't have to insert each userid in the vote table(too many users for each product).  What is the correct way to do this?

```
$query=  mysql_query("SELECT rate.voted as rvote, child.* FROM products child JOIN vote rate on child.id=rate.parentid WHERE rate.userid='8'") or die(mysql_error());
```

vote table

```
id | parentid |   userid |   voted  |
 1 |    1     |     6    |    1     |
 2 |    2     |     6    |    1     |
 3 |    1     |     4    |    1     |
 4 |    3     |     6    |    1     |
```

product table

```
id |     name     |
 1 |     bottled  |
 2 |     grain    |
 3 |     milk     |
 4 |     bread    |
```

php

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
$name = $row['name'];
$vote = $row['rvote'];

   echo $name;

   if($vote!=1) {
//like or dislike code
}



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to return the results for user `8`, using `JOIN`:

```
SELECT v.voted, p.*
FROM product p
LEFT JOIN vote v
  ON v.userid = 8
  AND v.parent_id = p.id
```

`voted` will be `1` for products that were voted on, and `NULL` otherwise.

With an index on the `id` column for the product table and a multi-column index on the `vote` table with the columns `(userid, parent_id)`, it should be pretty speedy.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from products
where id not in (select parentid from vote where userid = 8);
```

Answer (score 0):

This query will give you the desired result:

```
select * from product where id not in (select id from vote where userid =8 and (voted = 0 || voted =1))
```

Comment: It should be `...(select parentid from vote...`. Also, `and (voted = 0 || voted =1)` is not necessary if these are only values possible.